# Node.js 16 -> 17 changed resolution of "localhost"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, localhost

Under node.js 16.13.1 (Windows), code like this worked (assume a server exists and works fine):

```
import net from 'net';

let socket = net.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 12345
})
```

After updating to node.js 17.7.2, the above now throws ECONNREFUSED (connection refused) errors. However, it works fine with '0.0.0.0' instead of 'localhost'.

In fact, even the documented default of "localhost" (thanks VLAZ) fails on 17.7.2:

```
// connects with 16.13.1, ECONNREFUSED with 17.7.2:
net.createConnection({port:12345});

// connects with both versions:
net.createConnection({port:12345,host:'0.0.0.0'});

// connects with 16.13.1, ECONNREFUSED with 17.7.2:
net.createConnection({port:12345,host:'localhost'});
```

I've confirmed that the behavior depends on the version of node. I can reliably avoid / reproduce the behavior at will by switching node versions, using any code that establishes a network connection.

I have a fair amount of code with hosts that default to "localhost". I'd rather not update all of that to "0.0.0.0" if I don't have to. More tedious is that often the user provides the host address and expects "localhost" to work, so now I have to add logic that converts "localhost" to "0.0.0.0" every time I create a socket with a user-specified host address. I mean, I'll do what I have to do, but this kind of stinks.

My question is: What happened between 16.13.1 and 17.7.2 that made "localhost" not useable any more? Is it a bug, or some intentional change? And, is there a way to make it work again or do I have to find+replace "localhost" with "0.0.0.0" everywhere now?

I suspect a lot of the "connection refused to localhost" errors that people ask about on the internet are related to whatever changed...

---

Update: It seems to have something to do with changes in how interfaces are enumerated (or something like that) in 17, rather than the specific use of "localhost".

For example, with the following test setup:

- Three TCP servers created with node: one for the default address, one with "0.0.0.0" explicitly set, and one with "localhost" explicitly set.
- Three clients attempting to connect to each server, one to default host, one to "0.0.0.0", one to "localhost".

Then with 16.13.1:

|  | Listening on default | Listening on 0.0.0.0 | Listening on localhost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Connect to default | OK | OK | OK |
| Connect to 0.0.0.0 | OK | OK | OK |
| Connect to localhost | OK | OK | OK |

But with 17.7.2:

|  | Listening on default | Listening on 0.0.0.0 | Listening on localhost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Connect to default | OK | ECONNREFUSED | OK |
| Connect to 0.0.0.0 | OK | OK | ECONNREFUSED |
| Connect to localhost | OK | ECONNREFUSED | OK |

Now that's with servers created with node; also same node version for servers and clients. In my original case, my server was created with C++ and the standard `socket()` API, bound to `INADDR_ANY` (0.0.0.0).

Test code:

```
import net from 'net';

console.log(process.version);

const accepted = detail => socket => socket.write(detail, ()=>socket.end());

const serversReady = () => [ 
    new Promise(resolve => net.createServer(accepted('default')).listen(12345, function(){resolve(this)})),
    new Promise(resolve => net.createServer(accepted('localhost')).listen(12346, 'localhost', function(){resolve(this)})),
    new Promise(resolve => net.createServer(accepted('0.0.0.0')).listen(12347, '0.0.0.0', function(){resolve(this)}))
];

const ports = [[12345,'default'], [12346,'localhost'], [12347,'0.0.0.0']];
const hosts = [{}, {host:'localhost'}, {host:'0.0.0.0'}];

const clientsDone = () => ports.map(([port,whichserver]) => hosts.map(host => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let opts = {...host, port:port};
    net.createConnection(opts)
        .on('error', e => (console.log(opts, 'to:'+whichserver, 'error', e.message), reject(e)))
        .on('data', d => console.log(opts, 'to:'+whichserver, 'read', d.toString()))
        .on('end', () => resolve());
}))).flat();

Promise.all(serversReady())
    .then(servers => Promise.allSettled(clientsDone()).then(() => servers))
    .then(servers => servers.forEach(s => s.close()));
```

More on this after work but figured I'd post this little bit sooner rather than later. Will check 18 too.

Comment: Doesn't seem like the docs have anything to say here. In fact, it *should be correct*. The object passed to `createConnection()` is passed to [`socket.connect()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v17.x/api/net.html#socketconnectoptions-connectlistener) and that documentation states that `host` is expected to be a string and it is even defaulted to `'localhost'`. [The documentation looks the same for v16](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/net.html#socketconnectoptions-connectlistener)

Comment: @VLAZ Very strange. It's definitely associated with the version. In fact, I just confirmed that `socket.connect({port:1234})` (with defaulted host) fails on 17.7.2 and succeeds on 16.13.1. Now I'm wondering if maybe 17.7.2 enumerates network interfaces differently or something?

Comment: Dunno. Might be a bug somewhere, as you suggest. I don't know why it would ever fail - I'd expect to just use the OS to connect to the address. Which should try to resolve `localhost` from wherever it's held nowadays (I think I've not seen it in the hosts file). But I don't see how such a functionality would be different for different Node versions, if it's just expecting the outside to resolve this. Which suggests it's not actually what happens. But it's a mystery to me why.

Comment: Maybe try Node 18? Or a different version of 17? To try and isolate if it's some sort of bug. If it also behaves the same in 18, then it seems like a change of some sort.

Comment: Maybe "localhost" gets resolved to the IPv6 address and fails? Try to test with "127.0.0.1" and "::1", if one works and not the other.

Comment: This question applies to node 18 as well. I was trying to upgrade from 16 -> 18 and ran into this issue on my local dev environment.

Answer (score 5):

I quote answer from [@richardlau](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/40702#issuecomment-958157082)

> Node.js no longer re-sorts results of IP address lookups and returns
> them as-is (i.e. it no longer ignores how your OS has been
> configured). You can change the behaviour via the verbatim option to
> dns.lookup() or set the --dns-result-order command line option to
> change the default.

You could try:

> ping localhost

in you cmd or terminal. If it shows:

> Reply from 127.0.0.1

it means your system prefer ipv4 address to resolve **localhost**. If it shows:

> Reply from ::1

it means your system prefer ipv6 address.

You could [change system setting to prefer ipv4](https://superuser.com/a/436944/1550114). Node.js will resolve **localhost** to 127.0.0.1 as you expect.